# Sending id between web parts

Tags: web-part

I have 2 web parts.
One is a web parts with link buttons that represent the title of videos. 
The second is a html5 video player.

I need to send the id of a video from web part 1 to web part 2

Comment: Agree with user1901384: web part connections is the way to go with one caveat. Is this SharePoint Online or on-premises? What options do you have for deployment, as that may affect what you can achieve and would need a different answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this via connections. Here's an overview:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/connect-data-in-web-parts-HA010024105.aspx
Just open the menu in the right top of your webpart (in edit mode) and you'll see "Connection"-> "Get Parameters From" for example.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to not use server-side connections. As far as I see, you only need to pass an ID. As far as you do not need and do not need to do something heavy on a server side (such as working with server-side controls), you should take a look on javascript custom events.

[Custom events with jQuery](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/creating-custom-events-with-jquery.html)

```
$(document).on("myEvent", function (evt) {
   console.log(evt.data);
});

$.event.trigger({
   type:    "myEvent",
   data:    { id : 0, otherData : "Data" }
});
```

Also, you can try [native custom events](http://davidwalsh.name/customevent)